# cx_Freeze on complex python program

Tags: python-3.4, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create an executable out of a file that I have made with python. I got cx_Freeze to work, but once I try to open the exe file, it will say that "there is no module named ..." I am trying to make an executable out of a program that starts with:

```
import serial
import time
import re
import tkinter
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import os
```

My setup.py file currently looks like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("SerialComsCombined.py", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "4DCT_Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Serial Coms Combined",
    executables = executables
    )
```

I feel like the setup.py file needs to be modified. Any suggestions?